# Too many cases on switch statement?

Tags: php, performance, switch-statement

When does a php switch statement have too many cases? 100? 1000? 5000? 10000?
Of course it depends on the server, but imagine a simple VPS with 1 average core and 1 Gb of RAM, and several simultaneous requests.

I know this isn't good practice but I'm a curious person and I'm always learning.

Even using php-fpm I don't think it's wise to have hundreds of cases but the truth is I never tried this and would like to hear your opinion (SQL or MongoDB is what I may end up using for my idea).

Thank you very much for helping me with this dilemma!

Comment: If you have 1000's of individual statements on a single logic on your site you're doing something wrong and should probably use a hashtable and a loop instead.

Comment: What on earth are you doing that has more than 10 cases in a switch statement? Stop doing that.

Comment: I understand it's not good practice, I just want to know when too much is too much :) Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Can't speak specifically for PHP, but generally with switch statements, if you have to ask if it is too much, it is too much.

Comment: I agree... I'm not using this anywhere, it's just me thinking that I can start small but if I ever need to expand it may be a terrible idea...

Answer (score 0):

> When does a php switch statement have too many cases?

When you can no longer grok it in under about 20 seconds.

As h2oooooo says, you're then confusing process and data.